# Question about the proof of Cartan's structure equation in the context of pincipal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I have question about the proof of Cartan's structure equation in the context of pincipal bundle in Nakahara's book. The attached image is taken from the book.

To show that the curvature two-form $\Omega $ satisfies

$\Omega (X,Y) = {d_P}\omega (X,Y) + [\omega (X),\omega (Y)]$

The author divided the proof into three cases: i, $X,Y \in {H_u}P$, ii. $X \in {H_u}P$ and $Y \in {V_u}P$, iii. $X,Y \in {V_u}P$.

My problem is about the second case, the author said "Since  $Y \in {V_u}P$, there is an element  $V \in\mathfrak{g}$ such that $Y = {V^\# }$ ($ V^\# $ being the fundamental vector field generated by $V$) then $\omega (Y) = V$  is constant and hence $X\omega (Y) = X \cdot V = 0$"

If I look at the context  $Y$ is only required to be vertical such that ${\left. Y \right|_u} \in {V_u}P$, so $\omega (Y)$ should depend on $u \in P$ such that ${\omega _\mu }(Y) \ne {\omega _\nu }(Y)$ in general. Am I right? Or the author is just trying to say that $\omega (Y)$ must be constant along $X \in {H_u}P$? If this is the case then how to show it?
Thanks very much

Click here to see the picture  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05VRZ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $d\omega$ is a tensor, so the value of $d\omega(X,Y)$ at a point $u\in P$ depends only on $X(u)$ and $Y(u)$.

Comment: But $X(u)$ and $Y(u)$ all depend on $p$, right? if it is $X\omega (Y) = 0$ should not be zero in general.   The author is saying exactly the opposite thing, he said  $\omega (Y)$ is constant and thus $X\omega (Y) = 0$.

Comment: The given $X,Y$ are tangent vectors at $u$. You are choosing vector fields $\tilde X, \tilde Y$ with those values at $u$. The point of having a tensor field is that the answer is independent of your choices. I agree that $\tilde X\omega(\tilde Y)$ may be nonzero for some choices of the extension, but remember that there's a Lie bracket term, as well. The net result is well-defined.

Comment: BTW, are you the author of this mateiral? http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf ? Awsome stuff !! I actually started from this material to learn defferential geometry from last year, see how much I progressed now :)

Comment: Back to the business, if you look at the step 2 in the image, what really confuses me is that the author just assumed $Y = {V^\# }$ everywhere over the principal bundle #P(G,M)# right? is this an eligible thing to do here? My understanding is that $Y$ is vertical everywhere, but overall, we cannot say that $Y = {V^\# }$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's me. The author is sloppy. He writes $X,Y\in T_uP$ and then also uses the same letters for a choice of extension. As I've said, the answer is independent of these choices. Presumably he wants to choose $\tilde X$ to be horizontal everywhere, locally, and he chooses $\tilde Y = V^\sharp$. You may find that you want to look at more carefully written sources.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a recommendation of material containing this proof? better to be online material.

Comment: I haven't kept up with what is or is not on-line. Sorry.